# Анимации отдельных элементов в <TransitionGroup>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-animation, transition

Vue2

Есть некоторая часть кода. Элементы появляются снизу из прозрачности в список и идут вверх друг за другом. Через некоторое время элемент удаляется только со сдвигом влево и в прозрачность, а снизу элемент ждет, когда он полностью уйдет, после чего идет на его место, и так должно быть с любым элементом в списке.

Проблема заключается в том, что если удаляются одновременно несколько элементов, то происходит сдвиг вверх у некоторых этих элементов во время удаления. Есть ли возможность обрабатывать эти моменты?

```js
// Vue часть
...
<transition-group
    name="fade"
    tag="ul"
    class="list"
>
    <li
        v-for="notification in notifications"
        :key="notification.id"
        class="item"
    >
        {{ notification.id }}
    </li>
</transition-group>
...
// Scss часть
...
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.item {
    transition: transform 0.75s, opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.fade {
    &-enter {
        transform: translateY(100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    &-enter-active {
        transition-delay: 0.375s;
    }
    
    &-leave-to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    &-leave-active {
        transition: transform 0.375s, opacity 0.375s ease-in-out;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    &-move {
        transition: transform 0.375s, opacity 0.375s ease-in-out;
        transition-delay: 0.375s;
    }
}
```